# Mongoose - aggregate and group dates for filtering

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregation

I have some problems with data aggregation on mongoose. Would appreciate some help.

Here is my DB (minimized):

```
    {
        _id: 1,
        timestamp: 2018-05-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
   },
   {
        _id: 2,
        timestamp: 2019-10-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        timestamp: 2019-12-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        timestamp: 2020-01-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
    },
    {
        _id: 5,
        timestamp: 2020-02-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
    },
    {
        _id: 6,
        timestamp: 2020-09-27T22:02:07.837+00:00,
    }
```

Here's the structure I'm aiming for:

```
   [
      [2018,5],
      [2019,10],
      [2019,12],
      [2020,1],
      [2020,2],
      [2020,9]
    ]
```

currently my code is:

```
  Model.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$year", months: { $addToSet: "$month" } } }
  ]);
```

**[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qFWUvdyYuYp)**

But I feel I'm quite far from what I try to achieve.
Would appreciate some insights, thanks everyone!!

Comment: Is this what you need? https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xnl1iUSJ3fg

Comment: @Rfroes87 Not exactly. Note how when you add new documents, they are added too. I need unique Year + Month. Imagine a blog that exist a few years, I want to show a list with all the unique months that posts were written. After 5 hours I came up with a solution alone, posting an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 5 hours I made it.
Solution:
**https://mongoplayground.net/p/gFpFiK8vjkk**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
          { $group: { _id: { year: { $year: "$timestamp" }, month: { $month: "$timestamp" } }, total: { $sum: 1 } } },
          { $sort: { "_id.year": -1, "_id.month": -1 } },
  
])
```

Comment: You don't need `$unwind` (it is used with arrays). You can just use the sort as second stage of your aggregation pipeline: `{ $sort: { "_id.year": -1, "_id.month": -1 } }`. And, you don't need the third and fourth stages.

Comment: @prasad_ You're right, I'll update the answer. Thank you for that! It was there because I originally wanted to get a different data structure response but I gave up.